# how to implement slider same as calendar application in ipad?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented ipad application in which i want to implement slider same as calendar application in ipad.i dont know how to implement.please help me for this query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Custom sliders for iPhone and iPad are easy to implement with 3 static images.
The iOS manages user interaction and display.
The challenge for you will be to create resource images.

Good luck!

```
  // Create Slider
  UISlider slider = [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20)] autorelease];

  // Set thumb image
  [slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-thumb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

  // Set left image
  [slider setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-left.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  // Set left image
  [slider setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-right.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  // Set slider value, min and max
  slider.minimumValue = 1;
  slider.maximumValue = 100;
  slider.value = 1;

  // Add slider to view, self is a UIViewController
  [self.view addSubview:slider];
```